# #R #Non-numeric argument for binary operator #xts object * integer

Tags: r, error-handling, time-series, xts, finance

I have an xts object. Thus a time series of "outstanding share" of a company that are ordered by date.
I want to multiply the time series of "outstanding shares" by the factor 7 in order to account for a stock split.

```
> outstanding_shares_xts <- shares_xts1[,1]
> adjusted <- outstanding_shares_xts*7
```

Error: Non-numeric argument for binary operator.

The ts "oustanding_shares_xts" is a column of integers.
Does anyone has an idea??

Comment: Please check if your matrix in the xts is a numeric matrix and not a character matrix. This happens a lot when you do not exclude the date from the data.frame when creating the xts object. Otherwise, please include a sample of your data in the question with `dput(head(shares_xts1, 10))`. And read this on how to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that they may *look* like integers but are in fact not.

Sleuthing:

- I initially thought it could be `[`-vs-`[[` column subsetting, since `tibble(a=1:2)[,1]` does not produce an integer vector (it produces a single-column tibble), but `tibble(a=1:2)[,1] * 7` still works.
- Then I thought it could be due to `factor`s, but it's a different error:

  ```r
  data.frame(a=factor(1:2))[,1]*7
  # Warning in Ops.factor(data.frame(a = factor(1:2))[, 1], 7) :
  #   '*' not meaningful for factors
  # [1] NA NA
  ```
- One possible is that you have `character` values that *look* like integers.

  ```r
  dat <- data.frame(a=as.character(1:2))
  dat
  #   a
  # 1 1
  # 2 2
  dat[,1]*7
  # Error in dat[, 1] * 7 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
  ```

  Try converting that column to integer, something like

  ```r
  str(dat)
  # 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
  #  $ a: chr  "1" "2"
  dat$a <- as.integer(dat$a)
  str(dat)
  # 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
  #  $ a: int  1 2
  dat[,1]*7
  # [1]  7 14
  ```